# Function that randomly returns one of three options, where all options have the exact same chance?

Tags: javascript, random

I know this may have been asked before, but I'm trying to have a Javascript function return one of three options. The problem is the chance for each option should be completely equal.
This is what I have so far:

```
var choice = Math.random();
if (choice <= 0.34) {
    choice = "option1";
} else if (choice <= 0.67) {
    choice = "option2";
} else {
    choice = "option3";
}
```

This is already pretty accurate, however the probability of "option3" is slightly lower. How can I reformulate this to have each option have the same chance of occuring? I would prefer a solution that doesn't involve using "0.3333333333333333..." in the if condition or something like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it would be cleaner and simpler to do something like this:

```
var options = ["option1", "option2", "option3"];
var choice = options[Math.floor(Math.random()*options.length)];
```

Answer (score 3):

basicaly its your + Alex´s solution but i find that more beautiful

```
options=['option1','option2','option3']
choice = options[Math.floor(Math.random()*options.length)]
```

Comment: Woah, did we just write exactly the same code, or did you just copy me?

Comment: At least someone knows how to use Math.floor! +1 - all others deserve a -1 cause they are wrong!

Comment: I think it was just a coincidence, since we each used different quotes.

Comment: @Alex Walker's answer sounds right to me, is it not? o.o

Comment: @Retr0spectrum i guess we both copied the same and transformed it to suit the question :)

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying the random number by 3 will allow you to do this without using decimals or fractions:

```
var choice = Math.random() * 3;
if (choice <= 1) {
    choice = "option1";
} else if (choice <= 2) {
    choice = "option2";
} else {
    choice = "option3";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this hard style:

```
var choice = ['first', 'second', 'third'][Math.floor(Math.random()*3)]
```

Comment: 0 - 0.49 gets rounded to 0, 0.5 - 1.49 gets rounded to 1, 1.5 - 2 will be a 2. So - nope - not right. Use `Math.floor(Math.random()*2)` instead

Comment: Still has to be * 3 ;)